# IE input not working

Tags: html, angularjs, css

Input fields, selections dropdowns stopped working in IE. 
Check boxes cant be checked, text fields have the placeholde text at plain text, dropdowns cant be activated.

If I click a checkbox, it dosent change. Dropdowns dont drops, and placeholder text in input type=text is plain text in the textbox.

Example with checkboxes:
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optionnewwomen" ng-click="includeNewProfilesListsearch('Kvinde', true)"  ng-model="checkboxwomannewprofilessearch" ng-false-value="0" ng-true-value="1"
<label for="optionnewwomen"></label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

input[type=radio] + label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 2px #adadad;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 2px #adadad;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {
    content: "\2022"; /* Bullet */
    color: #21c365;
    border: solid 2px #21c365;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 13px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
    content: "\2714"; /* Tick */
    color: #21c365;
    border: solid 2px #21c365;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

I found some articles about IE problems with ::before, but no clear solution to that problem. Anyone having experience with this problem?

I dont know if the problem is related to Angular, but I doubt it.

Comment: This is not a clear question. What's the problem? It seems an AngularJS problem because the checkboxes works perfectly in each browser. Share your javascript code! Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The checkboxes works fine with Angular if I remove the css og label in the html. The problem is clear. That CSS and HTML isent working in IE11, but it works fine in Edge.

Comment: The problem is not clear. *Don't work* is not a clear statement. Please, read the two links that I share with you. Both of them are **mandatory** to read if you don't know the rules in stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a mathematician and coding type. Not gramma and spelling, especially not on another languish than Danish. I also thought that StackOverflow was for people like me, and not the spelling gramma types. If that is the case, then I’m moving alone.

Comment: Well, your code works even in IE 9, so... yeah. http://plnkr.co/edit/9ejoHYWIRkHSFqrlCBt5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.. Thats give me something to go further with.

Answer (score 0):

This line of yours

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optionnewwomen" ng-click="includeNewProfilesListsearch('Kvinde', true)"  ng-model="checkboxwomannewprofilessearch" ng-false-value="0" ng-true-value="1"
<label for="optionnewwomen"></label>
```

I'm not sure but it seems like this typos is causing it.

Try changing into this;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optionnewwomen" ng-click="includeNewProfilesListsearch('Kvinde', true)"  ng-model="checkboxwomannewprofilessearch" ng-false-value="0" ng-true-value="1">
<label for="optionnewwomen">Label here</label>
```

I'm not sure, but your missing the closing tags ">" in your input this might the cause why your checkbox is not rendered properly.

Comment: Thats a copy paste error. It still nok working in IE11